# Can I use two separate USBs to solve my GTA Storage Problem?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Could I use two separate USBs and combine their space together? I have two separate USBs but neither can hold 8gb on it's own.  But, combined they could hold the 8gb.  Is there anyway I could combine them?

Answer (score -1):

No, it is possible if you jailbreak and do bunch of things that an ordinary person cannot do. But for ordinary people like me and you.. and the rest of the 99.999% of the population, In order to run the game, you need to have 8gb of memory. Two flash drives will not work.